# Set DocumentRoot on local directory in apache

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, digital-ocean

I got a local directory, which will need a `DocumentRoot`. 
When I go to `serverip/nivon-zuidholland` I must have a DocumentRoot of `public`.

How would I manage this in apache2 config?

I inserted this in my `apache2.conf`. I tried to put this into my `sites-available/nivon-zuidholland.conf` but this doesn't work as well.

I can't restart apache2 because it returns `DocumentRoot not allowed here`.

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/nivon-zuidholland">
   AllowOverride All
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html/nivon-zuidholland/public
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. In your `/etc/hosts` add this:

   `127.0.0.1   nivon-zuidholland.local`
2. Create a directory: `/var/www/nivon-zuidholland` (set group to `www-data`)
3. Create a Virtual host file: `/etc/apache2/sites-available/nivon-zuidholland.conf`

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerName nivon-zuidholland.local
       ServerAdmin webmaster@nivon-zuidholland.local
       DocumentRoot /var/www/nivon-zuidholland

       ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/nivon-zuidholland_error.log
       CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/nivon-zuidholland.log combined
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
4. Place a symbolic link to this vhost conf file in `sites-enabled` directory

   ```
   ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/nivon-zuidholland.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/nivon-zuidholland.conf
   ```
5. Restart Apache server: `sudo service apache2 restart`

You should be able to access the site by going to: http://nivon-zuidholland.local/